# How to Update bubble chart in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, circle-pack

I managed to create a bubble chart which works fine when it is a single dataset. But something goes wrong if I need to update it with other datasets. Please help me with my update function at http://jsfiddle.net/9jL64/.

```
function changebubble(root)
{
  var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
      .data(bubble.nodes(classes(root))
      .filter(function(d) { return !d.children; }));

  node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });  
  node.select("circle")
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.r; })
    .style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i); });

   node.transition().attr("class", "node")
     .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });

   node.append("circle")            
     .attr("r", function (d) { return d.r; })
     .style("fill", function (d, i) { return color(i); });

   node.exit()
     .remove();

// Returns a flattened hierarchy containing all leaf nodes under the root.
function classes(root) 
{
  var classes = [];

  function recurse(name, node) {
    if (node.children)
      node.children.forEach(function(child) { recurse(node.name, child); });
    else
      classes.push({packageName: name, className: node.name, value: node.size});
  }

  recurse(null, root);
  return {children: classes};
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the classic case when you need to capture the enter selection on the `svg:g` group element in order to apply the enter/update/exit pattern correctly. But, to keep [object constancy](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/constancy/), and so that your labels still point to the right elements, you also need to key your data based on some data property of interest (`d.className`, which is generated from `d.name`).

Here is the main segment of your revised bubble update function:

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
    .data(
        bubble.nodes(classes(root)).filter(function (d){return !d.children;}),
        function(d) {return d.className} // key data based on className to keep object constancy
    );

// capture the enter selection
var nodeEnter = node.enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
    });

// re-use enter selection for circles
nodeEnter
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) {return d.r;})
    .style("fill", function (d, i) {return color(i);})

// re-use enter selection for titles
nodeEnter
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
        return d.className + ": " + format(d.value);
    });
```

The complete [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/CCRb5/) is here.

I also [blogged](http://www.fernoftheandes.com/blog/blog005/index.html) on the matter of applying the enter/update/exit pattern to `svg:g` elements, if you are interested.

Comment: Oh that's Andes.. This what i need, Thanks for ur work.