# d3 bubble chart circle whitespace doesnt go away

Tags: d3.js, visualization, bubble-chart

I have some data and I'm trying to visualize with d3.js, very new to me. 
I am able to get it to show up in a bubble chart h n somewhat filter it. But when it filters, it keeps the white space of where other circles used to be. Anybody known how to fix this?
http://bote795.github.io/semanticsVisualization

Thanks

Comment: You need to rerun the layout. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825126/how-to-update-bubble-chart-in-d3-js

Comment: The reason is that you are filtering the json after the passing it to the bubble layout. try filtering records and pass it to bulle layout that will fix the problem

Comment: Not sure what u mean, -lars
I tried doing that Cyril but it didnt seem to make a difference

Comment: nvm Cyril, tried again what you said and that work with the help of what lars  said as well.