# d3 animating a bubble chart within a given radius

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image]

//bubble chart base.
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1450/

I am trying to animate the bubbles - via changing their scale -- and if possible fade them in and out. At some stage I need to cluster them with some kind of gravity to occupy more of a containing circumference.

```
(function() {

    var diameter = 250;

    var svg = d3.select('#graph').append('svg')
      .attr('width', diameter)
      .attr('height', diameter);

    var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
      .size([diameter, diameter])
      .value(function(d) {
        return d.size;
      })
      .padding(3);

    var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
      .domain(["Lorem ipsum", "dolor sit", "amet", "consectetur", "adipisicing"])
      .range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56"]);


  function randomData() {

      var data1 = {
        "children": [
                {
                  name: "AA",
                  className: "aa",
                  size: 170
                },
                {
                  name: "BB",
                  className: "bb",
                  size: 393
                },
                {
                  name: "CC",
                  className: "cc",
                  size: 293
                },
                {
                  name: "DD",
                  className: "dd",
                  size: 89
                }
              ]
      };

      var data2 = {
        "children": [
                {
                  name: "AA",
                  className: "aa",
                  size: 120
                },
                {
                  name: "BB",
                  className: "bb",
                  size: 123
                },
                {
                  name: "CC",
                  className: "cc",
                  size: 193
                },
                {
                  name: "DD",
                  className: "dd",
                  size: 289
                }
              ]
      };



          var j = Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1);
          console.log("j", j);

          if (j == 1) {
            return data1;
          } else {
            return data2;
          }

        }

  change(randomData());

  d3.select(".randomize")
    .on("click", function() {
      change(randomData());
    });

  function change(data) {
    console.log("data", data);

    // generate data with calculated layout values
    var nodes = bubble.nodes(data)
      .filter(function(d) {
         return !d.children;
      }); // filter out the outer bubble


    var vis = svg.selectAll('circle')
      .data(nodes);

    vis.enter()
      .insert("circle")
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
      })
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        return d.className;
      });

    vis
      .transition().duration(1000)

    vis.exit()
      .remove();

  };

  })();
```

Comment: I have animation on the bubbles - but its still not right  http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1457/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1458/

Comment: bubbles = bubbles.transition()
       .transition()
       .duration(2000)
       .attr('transform', function(d) {
              return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
            })
       .attr('r', function(d) {
             //console.log("dr", d.r)
              return d.r;
            })
       .ease('sine')

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @ksav - actually a bigger part of a problem for this chart -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39153035/d3-dougnut-bubble-pie-chart  -- I need the bubbles to correspond, gravitate to their parent pie slices -- so orange bubbles near the orange slice, red bubbles near the red slice -- and also work efficiently during an animation

Comment: @ksav how do I get the bubbles to group together in a particular order --

Comment: -- How do I cluster these orbs -- so they are batched together in a circular configuration -- according to their parent segments -- https://codepen.io/fabiobiondi/pen/riDkK

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1481/ - tried making a custom bubble chart

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825126/how-to-update-bubble-chart-in-d3-js check this

Comment: -- Dragon slayer -- check out this end solution -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176404/d3-js-clustering-bubbles-to-segments/39187707#39187707

Comment: I am having issues getting the pie arc to tween first -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176404/d3-js-clustering-bubbles-to-segments/39187707#39187707

Comment: -- I have adapted the old bubble chart code -- so the situation is -- the pie chart is made and I plot placeholders in the mid-arc-slices -- then the child bubble chart is made in those placeholders

Comment: @Dragon_Slayer there is a bounty to solve this

Comment: @ksav there is a bounty to solve this

Answer (score 0):

These animated bubbles will be part of this overall chart - I need support in fine-tuning the animated arcs and bubbles accordingly. So the pie chart arcs should tween smoothly -- and the bubbles should fade in/out/grow in radius/reduce in radius

[image]

Latest fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1505/

( http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1506/ )- refactored

```
 1. -- how to animate the arcs
 2. -- how to animate the bubbles
 3. -- adding back the randomise button to test with 2 dummy data sets.
```

---

this is the old pie animations and worked very well

```
                /* ------- ANIMATE PIE SLICES -------*/
                var slice = doughpie.select(".slices").selectAll("path.slice")
                  .data(pie(data), key);

                slice.enter()
                  .insert("path")
                  .style("fill", function(d) {
                    return color(d.data.label);
                  })
                  .style("transform", function(d, i){
                    //return "translate(0, 0)";
                  })
                  .attr("class", "slice");

                slice
                  .transition().duration(1000)
                  .attrTween("d", function(d) {
                    this._current = this._current || d;
                    var interpolate = d3.interpolate(this._current, d);
                    this._current = interpolate(0);
                    return function(t) {
                      return arc(interpolate(t));
                    };
                  })

                slice.exit()
                  .remove();
                /* ------- ANIMATE PIE SLICES -------*/
```

//this is the current pie arcs - but when I try and animate the pie in the same manner - it fails.

```
var g = svg.selectAll(".arc")
  .data(pie(data))
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "arc");

g.append("path")
  .attr("d", arc)
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.data.label);
  });

arc
  .outerRadius(radius - 10)
  .innerRadius(0);
```

Comment: - anyone able to help out with this?

Answer (score 0):

Try and animate the pie chart first, then review the bubble animation

Answer (score 0):

To animate the bubbles (grow in) use:

```
vis.enter()
      .insert("circle")
      .attr('transform', function(d) {
        return 'translate(' + d.x + ',' + d.y + ')';
      })
      .attr('r',0)
      .transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .attr('r', function(d) {
        return d.r;
      })
      .style("fill", function(d) {
        return color(d.name);
      })
      .attr('class', function(d) {
        return d.className;
      });
```

I tried adding this code to the jsfiddle you posted above : http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1450/