# d3 Line Chart animations from left to right

Tags: javascript, d3.js

[image: Line chart growth]

I am interested to create a line chart -- that draws itself from left to right -- essentially connecting dots in the x-axis.

http://bl.ocks.org/markmarkoh/8700606
http://bl.ocks.org/duopixel/4063326

This is the jsfiddle that I've made to start creating this chart.
http://jsfiddle.net/NYEaX/1512/

```
//__invoke line
$('[data-role="line"]').each(function(index) {
  createLine(this);
});



function createLine(el){
    var w = $(el).data("width");
    var h = $(el).data("height");

    var svg = d3.select($(el)[0])
      .append("svg")
      .attr("width", w)
      .attr("height", h);

    var data = d3.range(11).map(function(){return Math.random()*10})
    var x = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([0, 700]);
    var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 10]).range([10, 290]);
    var line = d3.svg.line()
      .interpolate("cardinal")
      .x(function(d,i) {return x(i);})
      .y(function(d) {return y(d);})

    var path = svg.append("path")
      .attr("d", line(data))
      .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
      .attr("stroke-width", "2")
      .attr("fill", "none");

    var totalLength = path.node().getTotalLength();

    path
      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
      .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

    svg.on("click", function(){
      path      
        .transition()
        .duration(2000)
        .ease("linear")
        .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength);
    });



    /* plot axis */
    var padding = 100; // space around the chart, not including labels

    // define the x axis
    var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
        .orient("bottom")
        .scale(x);
        //.tickFormat(date_format);

    // draw x axis with labels and move to the bottom of the chart area
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "xaxis axis")  // two classes, one for css formatting, one for selection below
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (h - padding) + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

    /* plot axis */
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution that you can do is to append svg circles that correspond with the path before drawing the path. Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/stancheta/ystymLm4/6/

```
    var circles = svg.selectAll("dot")
      .data(data)
      .enter().append("svg:circle")
      .attr('class', 'circ')
      .attr("r", 3)
      .attr("cx", function(d, i) { return x(i); })
      .attr("cy", function(d, i) { return y(d); })
      .style('fill', 'lightsteelblue');
```

Comment: Yes that's good man -- how would I tidy up the axis -- remove the black lines essentially -- I wasn't sure also about how to create some fake json data with a date range and if indeed to adjust the x scale to a timescale?

Comment: If you want to change the minimum amount of code, I've updated the fiddle to mimic the image above: http://jsfiddle.net/stancheta/ystymLm4/7/ and put in some comments to explain what I changed. Let me know if they are unclear.

Comment: That looks good man -- there is a bounty if you want to help solve this part --- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39156400/d3-animating-a-bubble-chart-within-a-given-radius/39197206#39197206